# Solving the system $5(\sin x + \sin y) = 1$ and $5(\sin 2x + \sin 2y) = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

To find the general solution $(x,y)$ satisfying the system of equations
\begin{align} 5(\sin x + \sin y) &= 1 \\ 5(\sin 2x + \sin 2y) &= 1
\end{align}
I applied $\sin C + \sin D$ rule and then divided these two equations, then I am stuck at
$$\cos\frac{x-y}{2} = 2\cos \frac{x+y}{2}\cos(x-y).$$

I do not know what to do further.

Comment: Have you tried using double angle formulas?

Comment: Yes,  than also I was not getting simple equation.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  Do you have any reason to believe this has a simple exact answer? It appears to me to be 4th degree polynomial.

Comment: Actually,  Some  user of some website asked me this question, & according to him, there exists  value of 6 possible values of( x,y) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,$$
\begin{cases}
\sin x + \sin y = \dfrac{1}{5}\\
\sin 2x + \sin 2y = \dfrac{1}{5}
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow \begin{cases}
\sin \dfrac{x + y}{2} \cos \dfrac{x - y}{2} = \dfrac{1}{10} & (1)\\
\sin(x + y) \cos(x - y) = \dfrac{1}{10} & (2)
\end{cases}.
$$
Denote $u = \cos \dfrac{x - y}{2}$, $v = \sin \dfrac{x + y}{2}$, then (1) and (2) imply$$
\begin{cases}
uv = \dfrac{1}{10}\\
(2u^2 - 1) v \sqrt{1 - v^2} = \pm \dfrac{1}{20}
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow \begin{cases}
uv = \dfrac{1}{10} & (3)\\
(2u^2 - 1)^2 v^2 (1 - v^2) = \dfrac{1}{400} & (4)
\end{cases}.
$$
Since $v = \dfrac{1}{10u}$ by (3), eliminating $v$ from (4) yields$$
(2u^2 - 1)^2\left( 4u^2 - \frac{1}{25} \right) = u^4\\
\Longrightarrow 16 (u^2)^3 - \left( \frac{4}{25} + 17 \right) (u^2)^2 + \left( \frac{4}{25} + 4 \right) u^2 - \frac{1}{25} = 0.
$$

Note that $-π < y \leqslant x \leqslant π$ implies $l$ Now, there are six solutions to the last equation (see [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+16x%5E3-(4%2F25%2B17)x%5E2%2B(4%2F25%2B4)x-1%2F25%3D0)), i.e. $u_1, \cdots, u_6$. For each $u_k$, there is $v_k = \dfrac{1}{10u_k}$. Note that $\cos \dfrac{x + y}{2} = \pm \sqrt{1 - v^2}$. If $(2u_k^2 - 1) v_k > 0$, then$$
\frac{1}{20} = (2u_k^2 - 1) v_k \cos \frac{x + y}{2} \Longrightarrow \cos \frac{x + y}{2} = \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 - v_k^2}}.
$$
Otheriwise $(2u_k^2 - 1) v_k < 0$, then$$
\frac{1}{20} = (2u_k^2 - 1) v_k \cos \frac{x + y}{2} \Longrightarrow \cos \frac{x + y}{2} = -\sqrt{\smash[b]{1 - v_k^2}}.
$$
Thus for each $k$,$$
\begin{cases}
\cos \dfrac{x - y}{2} = u_k,\ \sin \dfrac{x - y}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 - u_k^2}}\\
\sin \dfrac{x + y}{2} = v_k,\ \cos \dfrac{x + y}{2} = ε_k \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 - v_k^2}}
\end{cases},
$$
where $ε_k \in \{\pm 1\}$ is determined as above. Since$$
\begin{cases}
\sin x = \sin \dfrac{x + y}{2} \cos \dfrac{x - y}{2} + \cos \dfrac{x + y}{2} \sin \dfrac{x - y}{2}\\
\cos x = \cos \dfrac{x + y}{2} \cos \dfrac{x - y}{2} - \sin \dfrac{x + y}{2} \sin \dfrac{x - y}{2}\\
\sin y = \sin \dfrac{x + y}{2} \cos \dfrac{x - y}{2} - \cos \dfrac{x + y}{2} \sin \dfrac{x + y}{2}\\
\cos y = \cos \dfrac{x + y}{2} \cos \dfrac{x - y}{2} + \sin \dfrac{x + y}{2} \sin \dfrac{x - y}{2}
\end{cases},
$$
there are twelve possible solutions $(\sin x, \cos x, \sin y, \cos y)$. After computing them numerically, it turns out that there are six distinct solutions.

Comment: can't    we find solutions in terms of x and constants, without using trigonometric functions.Like sin x = sin. a.    has x = nπ +(-1)^n a

Comment: After getting $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, the value of $x$ is uniquely determined up to an integer multiple of $2π$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose you have instead

$$
e^{ix}+e^{iy} = a\\
e^{2ix}+e^{2iy} = b
$$

then

$$
e^{2ix}+e^{2iy}+2e^{ix}e^{iy} = a^2\Rightarrow 2e^{ix}e^{iy} =a^2-b
$$

and now

$$
e^{ix}+e^{iy} = a\\
e^{ix}e^{iy} =\frac{a^2-b}{2}
$$

etc.

NOTE

Another way is to follow the trig. identities

$$
\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) = \frac a2\\
\sin(x+y)\cos(x-y) = \frac a2
$$

now calling

$$
\frac{x+y}{2} = u\\
\frac{x-y}{2} = v
$$

$$
\sin^2u\cos^2v = (1+\cos(2u))(1-\cos(2v)) = a^2
$$

or

$$
1+\cos(2v)-\cos(2u)-\cos(2u)\cos(2v) = a^2\\
\sin(2u)\cos(2v) = \frac a2
$$

and

$$
\sin(2u) = \frac a2\left(\frac{\cos(2u)-1}{1-a^2+\cos(2u)}\right)
$$

and now calling $\cos(2u) = z$ we have

$$
\left(\frac 2a\right)^2\left(\frac{z-1}{1-a^2+z}\right)^2=1-z^2
$$

This quartic should be solved to obtain the solutions. Attached a plot showing the intersections between the curves

$$
\sin x + \sin y = \frac 15 \;\;\mbox{in red}\\
\sin(2x)+\sin(2y) = \frac 15\;\;\mbox{in blue}
$$

[image]

Comment: Sir,  How you predicted about cos x and cos 2x which is  not mentioned in question as you are talking about e^(i x)

Comment: @Doraemon $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ have representations in terms of $e^{ix}$: $\frac{1}{2}i (e^{-ix} - e^{ix})$ and $\frac{1}{2}i (e^{-ix} + e^{ix})$.

Comment: @Doraemon He is using the (basically a very useful definition) $\sin(x) = \text{ Imaginary part of } e^{ix}$.

Comment: I got that,  but I am not getting How we will get 6 solutions of this system of equations according to Wolfram alpha

Comment: This doesn't really work because we don't know what the real part is

Comment: Please Elaborate your answer @Cesareo

Comment: @Doraemon Please. See note attached at the answer text bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Easy to see that 
\begin{cases}
\sin y = \dfrac15-\sin x\\
2\sin y\cos y = \dfrac15 - \sin2x
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
\sin y = \dfrac15-\sin x\\[4pt]
\cos y = \dfrac12\dfrac{1-5\sin 2x}{1-5\sin x}.\\
\end{cases}
Then
$$\dfrac1{25}\left(1-5\sin x\right)^2 + \dfrac14\left(\dfrac{1-5\sin 2x}{1-5\sin x}\right)^2=1,$$
$$4(1-5\sin x)^4+25(1-5\sin 2x)^2 = 100(1-5\sin x)^2,$$
$$4\left(\sin^2\dfrac x2-10\sin \dfrac x2\cos \dfrac x2 + \cos^2\dfrac x2\right)^4+25\left(\left(\sin^2\dfrac x2 + \cos^2\dfrac x2\right)^2-20\sin \dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2\left(\cos^2 \dfrac x2 - \sin^2 \dfrac x2\right)\right)^2 = 100\left(\sin^2\dfrac x2-10\sin \dfrac x2\cos \dfrac x2 + \cos^2\dfrac x2\right)^2\left(\sin^2\dfrac x2 + \cos^2\dfrac x2\right)^2,$$
and the subsitution 
$$t=\tan\dfrac x2$$
leads to the algebraic equation
$$4\left(t^2+1-10t\right)^4+25\left((t^2+1)^2-20t(1-t^2)\right)^2 = 100\left(t^2+1-10t\right)^2\left(t^2+1\right)^2,$$
or
$$(t^2+1)(71t^6-2840t^5-2187t^4+12320t^3-2187t^2-840t+71)= 0,$$
with the real roots
$$t\in\{-2.475108, -0.227373, 0.0758504, 0.356347, 1.617116, 40.453167\}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%5Cleft(t%5E2-10t%2B1%5Cright)%5E4-25%5Cleft((t%5E2%2B1)%5E2-20t(1-t%5E2)%5Cright)%5E2%20%2B%20100%5Cleft(t%5E2-10t%2B1%5Cright)%5E2%5Cleft(t%5E2%2B1%5Cright)%5E2)).

This means that
\begin{cases}
x_i=2\pi m+2\arctan t_i,\quad m\in\mathbb N\\[4pt]
\sin x_i = \dfrac {2t_i}{1+t_i^2}\\[4pt]
\sin 2x_i = \dfrac{4t_i(1-t_i^2)}{(1+t_i^2)^2}.\tag1
\end{cases}
On the other hand,
$$\tan\dfrac{y}2 = \dfrac{\sin y}{1+\cos y} = \dfrac{\dfrac15-\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}}{1+\dfrac12\dfrac{1-5\dfrac{4t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}}{1-5\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}}} = \dfrac25\dfrac{(1+t^2-10t)^2}{3(1+t^2)^2-40t},$$
$$\tan\dfrac{y_i}2 = \dfrac25\dfrac{(1+t_i^2-10t_i)^2}{3(1+t_i^2)^2-40t_i},$$
with the values
$$\tan\dfrac{y_i}2 = \{1.617116, 0.356347, 40.653167, -0.227373, -2.475108, 0.0758504\}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B2arctan%20t,%202t%2F(1%2Bt%5E2),%202arctan((2%2F5)(1%2B(-10%2Bt)t)%5E2%2F(3(1%2Bt%5E2)%5E2-40t))%7D,%20where%20t%3D%7B-2.475108,%20-0.227373,%200.0758504,%200.356347,%201.617116,%2040.453167%7D)).

These allow to calculate the solutions
$$\binom{x}{y} \in \left\{\binom{-2.373654}{2.033937}, \binom{-0.447144}{0.684637}, \binom {0.151411}{3.092406}, \binom{0.684637}{-0.447144}, \binom{2.033937}{-2.373654}, \binom{3.092406}{0.151411}\right\}+\binom{2\pi m}{2\pi n},\quad m\in\mathbb N,\quad n \in\mathbb N.$$
Substitution in the original system **confirms the correctness** of the solutions obtained.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Alex Francisco's answer
$$16 (u^2)^3 - \left( \frac{4}{25} + 17 \right) (u^2)^2 + \left( \frac{4}{25} + 4 \right) u^2 - \frac{1}{25} = 0$$ let $x=u^2$ to get the cubic
$$400 x^3-429 x^2+104 x-1=0$$ and use [the trigonometric method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Three_real_roots) for three real roots. This would give the nasty
$$x_k=\frac{143}{400}+\frac{7}{200} \sqrt{\frac{403}{3}} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  }{3}k-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{89421
   \sqrt{{3}}}{138229\sqrt{403}}\right)\right)\qquad (k=1,2,3)$$ which are all positive. Then six solutions for $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a general method to approach these kinds of problems is of interest to you. Let us define
 $\, X := e^{ix}, \, Y := e^{iy}. \,$ Use these new variables to express
the first equation as a rational function
 $\, 1 - 5(\sin(x) + \sin(y)) =  (2 X Y + 5 i (X Y - 1) (X + Y)) / (2 X Y). \,$
The second equation yields a similar result with $\, X,Y \,$ replaced by $\, X^2,Y^2. \,$ We now want to find when the numerators are both $\,0.\,$
The resultant of the two numerator polynomials, with respect to Y, is the polynomial
 $$ 100 X^5 
(250 i X^6 + (150-125i) X^5 - 290i X^4 - 229 X^3 + 290i X^2 + (150 + 125i) X -250i). $$

Excluding the $\, X^5 \,$ factor, this has $6$ complex roots for $\,X.\,$ Since $\,x\,$ is real, $\, |X| = 1.$ For each root $\,X\,$ there are two values of $\,Y\,$ each differing by the sign of the real part and exactly one of the two is also one of the $6$ roots for $\,X\,$ which makes sense since the two original equations are symmetric with respect to $\,x\,$ and $\,y.\,$ This means that there are $3$ distinct $\,x,y\,$ pairs of solutions.